# Custom web part broken once deployed

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, deployment

I have a custom web part I created that works in the local workbench and the hosted workbench both but just shows "An unexpected error occurred" after I deploy it to my site.

[image: unexpected error occurred]

In the console, I get a bunch of errors that say:

> [Report Only] Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'strict-dynamic' 'unsafe-eval' 'nonce-8071d1c9-2922-4d55-9646-83a09ac8d21a' ". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-OdsFlzz5N7GK0bIHVYdMGgT2x9qt9CFla/9QDXXEyXM='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

[image: console errors]

I found a similar issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/3881) but the issue was closed because the author stopped responding but the suspicion was that there was an issue with what the author had in their `render()` method.

To test, I commented out everything in my render method and replaced it with:

```
this.domElement.innerHTML = "<h1>Hellooooo World!</h1>";
```

Again it works in the local and hosted workbench but doesn't work at all once deployed:

[image: local workbench]

Answer (score 0):

I went back and re-read the [bug report](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/3881) I found and noticed that the OP was able to get it working if he turned off domain isolation which renders the web part in an `<iframe>` instead of a `<div>`.

I did the same and my custom web part began to work as expected. I changed `isDomainIsolated` to `false` in the package-solution.json:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/spfx-build/package-solution.schema.json",
    "solution": {
    "name": "MyWebPart",
    "id": "a624ed83-3f46-4892-978a-XXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "version": "1.0.0.0",
    "includeClientSideAssets": true,
    "webApiPermissionRequests": [
      {
        "resource": "UserApps_Service",
        "scope": "user_impersonation"
      },
      { 
        "resource": "Windows Azure Active Directory", 
        "scope": "User.Read" 
      }
    ],
    "isDomainIsolated": false
  },
  "paths": {
    "zippedPackage": "solution/MyWebPart.sppkg"
  }
}
```